# How to extract data and generate URL from it?

Tags: html, web-scraping, google-chrome-extension, web-crawler, data-extraction

I'm new to stackoverflow (Hello World!). I have some basic understanding of JS, C++, HTML, and CSS and I have been looking in this and other forums but I am having problems figuring out this one, mostly because I don't know what this would be called (TLDR at the bottom):

Essentially, I would like build a chrome extension that extracts data from a website (in this case, copart - a website where people sell cars) and create a link from it that opens another window to one of three car evaluators (edmunds, kbb, nada). I fix cars as a hobby but it's a pain to have to input vehicle info over and over so I wanted to automatize the process as much as possible. Hopefully this will help others as well.

E.g. a generic link to edmunds is: https://www.edmunds.com/ford/escape/2018/appraisal-value/?vin=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX. I would like to know how to extract the make, model, year and VIN, in this case, from copart ([Example copart page](https://www.copart.com/lot/64716471/clean-title-2020-chevrolet-impala-premier-ca-los-angeles)). On Kbb, e.g., all I see that can automatized is inputting the vin into the window and clicking "Go". Is there a way to have the plugin automatically select "VIN" and copy the VIN into the field while clicking the "Go" button?

[Kbb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhNCO.png)

I know, a lot of questions. I'm also not quite sure what this would be called? A crawler? A scraper? A craper? :)

Either way, here the basic (TLDR) question:

- How to create a chrome plugin that extracts data from one website, opens a URL using that data, and which then performs an action like switching a label, populating a textbox, and clicking a button on that URL?

I have only posed this question here so if there's a better place to put it, please let me know.

Mark

Comment: Take a look at [Chrome WebDriver](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/getting-started). This is a tool for automated testing of web applications, but it might do just what you need.

Comment: The way the question is worded _seems_ what you want is to extend the browser by adding custom behavior to specified website (scraping generally is to collect data and/or to automate things whereby opening a browser is not necessary). If this is correct and you are looking to build an extension, I suggest reading this guide first: <https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/getstarted /> You will want a implement a _content script_ to look for the make/model/year/VIN through javascript query selectors, then dynamically create a button whose click launches kbb.

Answer (score -1):

## Extracting data from one website and searching more for scraped data in other website

**1. For this project you can use combination of selenium and scrapy**

**2. Since both are dynamic page powered by javascript do need to check on security constraints**

**3. Can make use of spider under scrapy each spider with support of selenium**

**4. there is need of pressing Go button that can be achieved using selenium**